# Forwarding to start page after successful registration

Tags: php, http-redirect

I have a small login system on my site. I want the user to be redirected to the home page after the successful login. After several attempts with many possibilities, I still do not succeed.

This is my login script:

```
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                    require("mysql.php");
                    $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM $accounts WHERE email = :email");
                    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST["email"]);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
                    if ($count == 1) {
                        $row = $stmt->fetch();
                        if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $row["password"])) {
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                            ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-emerald text-center mb-50">
                                    You have been successfully registered
                                </div>
                                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-yale-blue mb-50">Continue</a>
                            <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-red-ncs text-center mb-50">
                                    The specified password is incorrect
                                </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    } else {
                        ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-red-ncs text-center mb-50">
                                An account with this email address was not found
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

I have already had these attempts:

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

```
header('Location: login.php?redirect=index.php');
```

I'm really looking forward to an answer as I've been stuck on the solution for several hours now!

Comment: Can you please specify the issue? Is it in the first or in the second block of code?

Comment: I would like "You have been successfully registered" to be replaced with the redirect to the home page.

Comment: See here: https://code-boxx.com/simple-login-php-mysql